# What are these strange black disc LEGO pieces?

Tags: part-identification

What are these discs? Ammo maybe or ice hockey pucks? I did not find any id numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be [Sports Hockey Puck, Large](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=bb116):

[image: piece image]

It comes from the larger Technic-based Sports Hockey sets from 2003-2004.

[image: set picture]

(Puck in the above set has stickers.)